# Syntax error initializing an array with save attribute

Tags: arrays, fortran

Is there a way in Fortran to store a static array like this or something similar

```
Real*8,Save,Dimension( 1 : 3 ) :: z = ( / 1 , 0 , 0 /)
                                       1
Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
```

The problem is if I define the array like that, I get

```
Real*8,Save,Dimension( 1 : 3 ) :: z = ( / 1 , 0 , 0 /)
                                       1
Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
```

I would like to store this array in a subroutine
which is called several times during the program execution,
but I do not want to initialise this array over and over again for
every subroutine call.  How can I declare this array?

Comment: Does the value of the array ever change?  Can you just use a named constant?

Comment: Yes you are right it is working indeed. The error which I had is quite surprising to me. I am not allowed to have a space between the "/" and ")" or "(" and "/". If I remove this everything is working fine. And for sure also by defining a constant this would work in my case. Thank You

Comment: I am not sure what is the question. What is *"not working"*? Do you have any error messages or wrong results which you can show? More code will be necessary if yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved already. The problem is if I define the array like, I get

```
Real*8,Save,dimension( 1 : 3 ) :: z = ( / 0d0 , 0d0 , 1d0 / )
                                       1
 Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
```

So with spaces between the brackets and the slash.
But if I do ( so I just remove the spaces ( at "( /" and "/ )" ) like this

```
Real*8,Save,dimension( 1 : 3 ) :: z = (/ 0d0 , 0d0 , 1d0 /)
```

it works fine.

Comment: you can also use `[ ]` instead of `(/ /)`.

Comment: Interesting! This seems to be easier. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is a handy feature from Fortran 2003.